# Consolidating multiple GET parameters into a single value

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

Im not really sure what im looking for but currently in my system i send a long url like this:

```
$name=1&option=2&field=4....
```

And its quite long. So if i have a list of values like:

- name
- option
- field

can i put them into a string in which i can break at certain points eg by a slash or whatever.

And then encode the string so its completely random like, so i only have one field to send:

```
&data=JKHFGDKGLKJHFKDJHFKJDHFKHDF
```

Then finally i can decode the other side and break apart.

Is there a pre-built function to do this?

WHAT IT IS:

im sending data to paypal, but i have a few custom variables i wish to send, now for some reason my IPN isnt geting them, not sure why, but if i add one called custom it get to the IPN fine. So i thought if i just send one called custom in a random format and then decode?

Comment: Have you \[considered\] the possibility to do this via `POST`?

Comment: Well if you encode the string so its *completely* random you will not be able to decode it.  What is you main objective here? Is it to make the url shorter or just to send all the data in a single string?

Comment: Why not save the data on your server, and map a "random token" to it. Send the token along to PayPal, who will return that and you can look up the data again?

Comment: @salathe, this is exactly what i wanted todo, and is the easiest option, my problem is the users are not registered so i ahve no userID to save the order againts, i was going to generate a random number, but how random would it be?

Comment: Surely having no user id is entirely unrelated to masking/encoding/whatever some data sent to PayPal?..

Comment: Yes, but when a user makes a order, i stored the data in the database, then pass to paypal, then on IPN return i approve order in database. but i dont have anything to look the order up by, in the past i would just use user ID, so a random toekn would work, but i guess

Comment: Could this be an example of [the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/164291)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply Base64-encode your data.

```
$a = array('name' => '1', 'option' => '2', 'field' => '4');
$temp = json_encode($a);       // convert array to string
$data = base64_encode($temp);  // encode string
```

output:

```
"eyJuYW1lIjoiMSIsIm9wdGlvbiI6IjIiLCJmaWVsZCI6IjQifQ=="
```

To send this in an URL, you must encode it once more (like you must encode all data you would send in a URL)

```
$url = $url . "&data=" . urlencode($data)
```

The intermediary step through JSON ensures your data will kep its structure and will be easily decodeable on the receiving side.

On the downside: Your URL will be longer.

Comment: @Lunar: I have no idea if this would work for your problem. I suggest you just try it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [base64_encode](http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) and then [base64_decode](http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php), this will solve your problem.

Comment: no, it wont. base64 encoded strings may contain `+=/` which are unsafe for use in URIs.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what you are looking for we can't imagine that lol.

Anyway If i got you, you can do this, considering you have built your string:

```
$string ="$name=1&option=2&field=4";
```

You could pass it as a single param with:

```
$data = url_encode($string);   
<a href="url?data={$data}"></a>
```

Other than `url_encode` you can use `base64_encode`

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter (Bobby) says - consider using POST when you want to send larger sets of data and prevent your URL from becoming unmanageably long or ugly.

GET variables are handy for providing the user with a page they can bookmark directly which is desirable in some cases, such as on a search page with a query string and/or filters already filled in, so that the user can return to a search and check for new results periodically without having to reset all of their choices.

POST variables are better if you don't need that sort of functionality, you don't need to encode/decode them for URLs and they can't be bookmarked directly (which is also desirable in many cases).

To answer your original question though, if you really, really had to send the variable(s) on the URL and you wanted to just send one apparently random string, I suggest writing a couple of encode/decode functions of your own (since I assume the object of the excercise is not to encrypt it against tampering, just to make your URLs friendlier).  This will be all the easier if there are restrictions to what the variables can be, and more difficult if they can be absolutely anything.

For example - if you have the following vars and possible settings:

- var1 *(apple, banana, orange)*
- var2 *(car, motorbike, bicycle)*
- var3 *(red, yellow, green)*

Normally, you'd make a URL like:

http://www.mysite.com/page.php?var1=banana&var2=car&var3=green

If you assign the variables to numbers (for example) so that var1, var2 and var3 would be 1, 2 or 3 - then you could send over a URL like:

http://www.mysite.com/page.php?vars=213

Break it down at the other end into single numbers and convert those back into 'banana', 'car', and 'green'.

But seriously.... I'd look at POST first unless there is very specific reason why you would use this sort of approach - i've used it before for shortening a URL to make it more sharable on social media and forums.